# Collection with fastest (concurrent) add operation

Tags: java, scala, collections, concurrency

I am looking for a collection which has the most efficient "add item" concurrent operation. Scala or Java is good.

I typically:

- insert 100.000s of entries, one at a time
- don't care about order
- only read and clear the collection when there is no append. So not critical

Also, it should work with multiple thread (hence the concurrent constraint). But I need it to be most effective when there is no concurrency: the design for concurrent-safety should not have too much impact when there is no concurrent access.

I use this collection to record performance measurements. This is why it should be the most efficient possible to not bias too much actual performance. However, because the collection size is possibly big and not known in advance, it should cope efficiently with size increase.

So which collection would be best to use?

I currently used a `mutable.ListBuffer` with `buffer.synchronized{ ... }` around append (and clear) operation. I tried to use a `var buf: List` (scala) with similar `synchronized{ ... }` block but it seriously impacted the measurements.

Comment: "insert 100.000s of entries, **one at a time**", "it should work with multiple thread". Well, which is it?

Comment: Have you considered just running the `add` operation asynchronously? Regardless of the ultimate collection or of whether actual adding is synchronized?

Comment: ConcurrentLinkedQueue looks like a good candidate

Comment: @Michael I meant 2 things : (1) the typical maximum size is couple of 100.000 entries ; and (2) the only critical operation is "add one item"

Comment: The number of items is irrelevant. Are you adding them concurrently or sequentially?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I don't understand, do you mean to not use `synchronized` ? How much it cost is an interesting question, but I'd like my measurement not to be missing entries when use in a concurrent execution

Comment: I added the typical size, just in case it matters. I can use the collection either concurrently or sequentially. So both, but the sequential case is the most important, with the concurrent still being correct but it is not as critical.

Comment: @Juh_ I mean the code that would call `collection.add` makes instead something like `collector.addAsync`, which would do the actual adding in the background. This, in my opinion, may minimize the cost imposed by the actual collection's `add` execution. As for whether that would be more performant than any collection's add execution, only testing can determine it (although I'd expect it to be consistent).

Comment: The code that call add doesn't know if it is run sequentially or concurrently. However I could switch which the add function to use depending on the situation.

Comment: You can go for parallel collection if your task can be done in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html). It's O(1) insertion using CAS. So under moderate load you probably won't have faster inserts. If you have very very high load, you may want to consider a [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).

Since you say it's likely going to be single-threaded on adds, using CLQ and CAS will be your best option.

Comment: For my case, I actually don't see much difference between several choices: LBQ seems a little slower than CLQ, nothing really notable though. But those have similar cost as a synchronized ListBuffer. And I even get similar cost with synchronized List if using the suitable add method (i.e. `::`). But for List I am not confident in the lock on a `var` though.

Comment: Yeah, LBQ is going to be slightly slower than CLQ under normal load. For all practical purposes, LBQ should be equal to the `synchronized` on add solutions.  Where LBQ or CLQ win is if you do use the queue put/take functionality (which I know you're only put).